# Node/Javascript setting object property to array not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = "a";
var ob = new Object();
ob.prop = arr;
ob.prop[0] = "b";
//Console log arr[0] returns b
```

for some reason, the arr array is being changed when I change ob.prop ?

What am I missing?

Comment: You've assigned a reference to the same Array.

Answer (score 1):

As **the system** pointed out, `ob.prop = arr` is basically just giving another name for accessing the object referenced by `arr`. So when you modify `ob.prop` you are modifying the same object that `arr` also refers to.

**EDIT**: For copying an array take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript):

```
var arrCopy = arr.slice();
```

Comment: So how would I go about creating a copy of arr instead of a reference to it?

Answer (score 1):

As Jorge mentioned, this is happening because `obj.prop` is just a reference to `arr`, so `arr` and `obj.prop` will point to the same place in memory. So if you change either, the value in memory (which the other is pointing to) changes, thus changing both.

If you're looking to avoid this you need to do a **deep copy**. This will copy the values of the array into a new array, which `obj.prop` will point at.

There is a walk-through of how to do this in javascript [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/deep-copying-of-objects-and-arrays/).